# Laravel form post validate error

Tags: php, laravel, validation, controller

From html part:

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" id="address" value="">
</form>
```

From controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'address' => 'required'
            ]);
```

it have the following error

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

If I remove the **'address' => 'required'**
it can run normally

Comment: maybe this helps {!! Form::open(['method' => 'post']) !!}

Comment: Can you show the Route you have for this url please. Method not allowed, I would assume you are using Route::get rather than Route::post

Comment: Error seems pretty clear. You are trying to POST to a route that is not a POST route. Please paste your route into your question

Comment: @Adam
Route::post('/signup', [
 'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
 'as' => 'signup'
 ]);

Comment: @RobFonseca here thanks

Comment: Where is your submit button? Doesn't seem like you are posting the entire form if it is just an address field. Are you submitting via AJAX? Definitely need more information. Posting the entire controller method and HTML form would help

Comment: @RobFonseca yes i have a normal submit button and token also "<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}"> "     but i omitted in the above, sorry